# Bring amount into Paypal BuyNow button from session variable

Tags: html, paypal

I have asp.net page with vb.net code behind which produces a money value (TotAmt) from various radio buttons when a calculate Button is pressed. I want to pass through value to Paypal page with Standard BuyNo Button.  I am not very experienced with Paypal.

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value=_s-xclick"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button-id" value="XXXXXXXXXXX"/>
<input type="text" name="amount" value= "TotAmt"
```

Help gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

You would just need to dynamically populate the "amount" variable in your button code.  However, to be able to dynamically populate the amount you need to create a non hosted clear text button.  You won't be able to populate the amount into a hosted button.

To generate a non-hosted/clear text button follow these steps:

1. Log in your PayPal account www.paypal.com
2. Click the tab "Merchant Services" to access the Merchant Tools tab.
3. In the Website Payment Standard section select the type of button you would like to create (Buy Now, Add to Cart, Donation, Etc…).
4. Click "Create your button now" to access to the PayPal Button Factory.
5. Fill out the fields you will need in your button (Item name, Price, Currency…).
6. Click the tab "Step 2: Track inventory (optional)" then uncheck the box "Save button at PayPal".
7. Click on "Create Button".
8. The encrypted HTML code of your button will be displayed.
9. Click on the link "Remove code protection"
10. The HTML code of your button will be displayed, click "Select Code" and copy it to your website.

Comment: I have done what you suggest before on another site. On this site, I don't want to show Item, Price, Quantity. I just want to pass a money amount to the BuyNow button.

Answer (score -1):

Create a session in code and pass amount to it, for example

```
session["amt"]=lable.text1;
```

and then in HTML use this code

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value='<?php echo $_SESSION["amt"]?>' /> 
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="confirm.php" />
```